# Unable to retrieve messages send and received by Facebook user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I executed the following query but I can't retrieve any results:

```
$fql_query = 'select message_id from message where message_id IN (SELECT message_id FROM message WHERE viewer_id='.$fbuser.')';
```

I got result for this query:

```
$fql_query = 'select gid, name from group where gid IN (SELECT gid FROM group_member WHERE uid='.$fbuser.')';
```

The app have both group and message read permission.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewer_id` in the [`message`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/message/) table is not indexable, so maybe you need to sub-query the [`thread`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/thread/) table, something like the below will get the `message_id` form the inbox folder (folder nb. **0**):

```
SELECT message_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0)
```

You can also use the Graph API, example:

```
/USER_ID?fields=inbox.until(1348523520).limit(25).fields(comments.fields(from,message))
```